# How to swap specific tags in string using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a string like

```
str = "< p>line 1< br>< /p>< p>lin2< br>< /p>< h1>line 3< br>< /h1>";
```

and i need to swap `< br>` with their immediate next closing tags which in the above case are `< /p>`, `< /p>` and `< /h1>`

so final str required is:

```
finalStr = "< p>line 1< /p>< br>< p>lin2< /p>< br>< h1>line 3< /h1>< br>";
```

I tried creating regex but was not successful. Can anyone guide how in this case i can create regex and swap the occurrences of br with the next closing tags only using JS ?
PS: i have added extra space in all tags so that the html editor can ignore reading them as tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try:

```
"< p>line 1< br>< /p>< p>lin2< br>< /p>< h1>line 3< br>< /h1>".replace(/(< br>)(< \/[\w\d]*>)/g,'$2$1')
//"< p>line 1< /p>< br>< p>lin2< /p>< br>< h1>line 3< /h1>< br>"
```

Comment: thanks, i do not have good understand of regex that is why needed a quick help..will learn more about creating regex

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to do dom manipulation using regex, instead you can try something like

```js
str = "<p>line 1<br></p><p>lin2<br></p><h1>line 3<br></h1>";
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = str;

var brs = div.querySelectorAll('br');
[].forEach.call(brs, function(br) {
  br.parentNode.parentNode.insertBefore(br, br.parentNode.nextSibling)
});
snippet.log(div.innerHTML)
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: I agree with you regarding dom manipulation, but actually intention was not to impact DOM, it was just to create some string out of DOM elements keeping DOM as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Simply try this

```
var str = "< p>line 1< br>< /p>< p>lin2< br>< /p>< h1>line 3< br>< /h1>";
var vca = str.replace(/<\sbr>(<\s\/\w>)/,"$1<br>");
```